# Can not reinstall microsoft edge, maybe powershell not working?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-edge

I tried to reinstall microsoft edge to my tablet with a 32-bit windows 10, because I could not start it. (Loading screen, after 10-30 sec it closed automatically). I followed a tutorial which says delete some folders and after that run the "Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers -Name Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml" -Verbose}" command in powershell.

My problem is, I think the powershell is not working. If I Open it, it loads up like this: [Start of powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1Hqk.jpg)

If i write any commands to it, nothing happens just eating 10-40% of processor.
For example I tried Get-ExecutionPolicy and after waiting 1 hour it does nothing. You can see the result after 1 hour here: [After 1 hour of waiting still nothing happened...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUW1z.jpg)

What could be the problem?
Is there any way to fix the powershell and/or the edge?
(I also tried to open, the powershell ISE but it crashes at the loading screen with the "application has stopped" standard windows error message)

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

I never had to reinstall Edge as in most cases a reboot did the job. If you don't find a way to reinstall Edge, you can also reset your PC through the Windows recovery options which should reinstall all system apps.

[image: Reset Windows 10]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've just make a clean install and everything works now.

Comment: Good to hear. If my answer was helpful in any way I would be happy if you could mark it as correct. Thanks.